# Why do the register values not match the values I put in them in the program?

Tags: assembly, x86

I started learning Assembly from a digital book I have and when I tried to run my program the values of the registers didn't match the instructions of the program.

I'm using x86 Assembly with TASM and TD and while learning I wrote a simple program with a few mov instructions to see the behavior and change of the IP register and I noticed that while the program is running the values of the other registers don't change accordingly and I don't understand why. For example, in the photo I added here you can see that the value of ax is 0 even though it should be 1234 by the instruction "mov ax, 1234h".[image]

Comment: You have a mismatch between source and binary. You are not running the program created from that source. The `8BC3` is `mov ax, bx` not `mov ax, 1234h`. Note that the title also says `(modified)`.

Comment: but why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You fix it by recreating the binary (run the assembler and the linker). Also make sure you are loading the binary you created.

Comment: Hit "save" in your editor and rebuild, then re-run inside the debugger.  IDK if DOS debuggers would support restarting a modified binary of if you'd have to quit the debugger and restart, setting breakpoints afresh.